# Для чего используется функция Эйлера в алгоритме RSA?

Tags: шифрование, rsa

Я разбираюсь с работой алгоритма RSA.
В нём, для формирования ключей необходимо определить модуль, состоящий из перемножения двух простых чисел. Это понятно. Потому что нахождение двух множителей для простого числа - сложная операция.

Дальше необходимо определить число e, используя функцию Эйлера. Функция Эйлера находит **количество** взаимно простых чисел в натуральном ряде, в котором макс.число меньше того, от которого находим.
С этого момента я никак не могу разобраться, зачем нам находить **количество** взаимно простых чисел? Так и ещё и от этого **количества** нужно определить любое взаимно-простое с самим же количеством. Как эта функция Эйлера нам помогает? Почему вместо e нельзя взять любое простое число, меньше модуля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас попробую подробнее объяснить. Когда мы доходим до места m^(ed-1) ≡ 1 (mod n), мы фактически получаем частный случай малой теоремы Ферма для взаимно простых m и n. Она же называется теоремой Эйлера. Формула Эйлера для случая, когда n - простое число выглядит как  φ(n) = n-1. То есть использование функции Эйлера это логическая подстановка, а взять взаимно-простое с самим же количеством надо для выполнения равенства ed ≡ 1 (mod φ(n)). Я кажется понимаю, что вы хотите постичь некий "физический смысл" этой подстановки, но это просто логически выведенный результат.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь надо уточнить что уравнение ed ≡ 1 (mod φ(n)) имеет решение только, если один из множителей является числом взаимно простым с φ(n), а иначе решения не существует. В нашем случае мы допускаем, что это будет e. Просто не совсем понятно почему "e - некоторое число взаимно простое с φ(n)". В остальном все так.

Comment: Я просто до сих пор не могу понять, почему используется именно количество. Оно же по-факту ни на что не влияет. Количество взаимно простых - это количество. Как оно влияет на формулу - я не поняла.

Comment: [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9) "выбирается целое число e (1<e<φ(n)), **взаимно простое** со значением функции φ(n)". Это часть условия. Очевидно, что и e^-1 mod φ(n) тоже взаимно простое с φ(n).